# Populate a ASP.NET UserControl Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatables

Is there anyway for a ASP.NET page with say a gridview on it to load a user control into a Modal popup. I would like to use the User Controls onload function but that is triggered when the parent page is loaded, not when you click on for example a link called 'edit' in the GridView.

I don't want to redirect to another ASP.NET page, I would like to popup the edit page which will contain many controls like Dropdowns and Listboxes that in themselves with contain hundreds of records.

I have tried using Ajax and JSON but the population of the dropdowns and listboxes is very slow.

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried using Ajax and JSON but the population of the dropdowns and listboxes is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time.

So, say a simple gv of hotels.

and our popup control is the user control that is a "form like" layout to edit the one row.

Note the "difficult" issue is if the user does edit, then we need to trigger a refresh of the grid. But, even that is quite easy.

So, say our gv - rather simple.

We drop in a plain jane button (for edit).

So, we have this markup (a gridview)

```
<div id="MyGridArea" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        CssClass="table table-hover" Width="60em" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EnableViewState="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn"
                        OnClick="cmdEdit_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="+Add" CssClass="btn myshadow" />
</div>
<br />

<uc1:MyEditHotelC ID="EHotel" runat="server"
    MyEditArea="MyEditArea"
    MyGridArea="MyGridArea"
    MyTable="tblHotelsA"
    MyTitle="Edit Hotel Information" />
```

Note our plain jane edit button.

And, right below the gv is our user control.

Note how I have some custom (public properties) of the UC.
In above, the "div" for "grid" is setup, and also I define the div for editing.

Ok, so code to load is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GridView1.DataSource = Myrst("SELECT * FROM [VtblHotelsA] ORDER BY HotelName")
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we now see/get this:

[image]

Ok, so now when we hit edit button?

We will get the current row, and THEN pop up our user control.

So, the code behind edit button is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Call EditOne(intPK)

End Sub

Sub EditOne(intPK As Integer)

    Me.EHotel.MyPk = intPK
    Me.EHotel.LoadData()
    Me.EHotel.MyFocusCancel()

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType,
                                        "popedit", "popedit()", True)

End Sub
```

and now we see this:

[image]

I also have a pubic event for the UC. (since if the user edits, we need to re-load (re-display) the gv on this current page.

So, how does the UC pop up that dialog?

The UC uses jQuery.UI. (it does not matter what/which library you use to pop a dialog, but you should pick one and "run" with it.

So, the markup for the UC ALSO includes the jQuery pop dialog.

The markup for the UC is just a "div" and the jquery dialog code.

It looks like this:

```
    <div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="float:left;display:normal" clientidmode="Static"  >

        <br/>
        <style>
            .iForm label {display:inline-block;width:90px}
            .iForm span  {display:inline-block;font-weight:700
            }
            .iForm input {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}                
            .iForm select {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:10px;height:24px;margin-left:-3px}                
            .iForm textarea {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}     
            .iForm input[type=checkbox] {margin-right:8px}
        </style>
        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
            <label>HotelName</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HotelName" width="280">
            </asp:TextBox> <br />
                <label>First Name</label>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
                <label>Last Name</label>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
       
            <label>City</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="140px" 
                DataTextField="City" 
                DataValueField="id"
                f="City_ID" >
            </asp:DropDownList>                
            
            <br />
            <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
```

(etc. etc. etc.). It just the layout in a div for editing the hotel.

And the pop dialog code is this:

```
   <div id="mydelpop" style="display:none">
       <h4>Really delete this Hotel?</h4>
   </div>

   <script>
       function popedit() {

            MyPWidth = "62em"
            MyWidth = $(window).width()

            if (MyWidth < 840) {
                MyPWidth = (MyWidth - 25)  + 'px'
            }

            var myDialog = $("#EditRecord");
            myDialog.dialog({
                title: "Edit Hotel",
                width: MyPWidth,
                modal: true,
                appendTo: "form",
                dialogClass : "dialogWithDropShadow",
                close: myclose
            });
       }

       function myclose() {
           var myDialog = $("#EditRecord");
           myDialog.dialog('close')
           // myDialog.find("form").remove();
           // destory the instance, but only
           // if exists (if we dont' clean up then button 
           // clicks don't work on 2nd use of dialog)
           if (myDialog.hasClass('ui-dialog-content')) {
               myDialog.dialog('destroy');
           }
       }
 </script>
```

So, the edit code, the JavaScript parts are part of the UC.

I only have to "set" the values for the UC, and of course "pop" the dialog by injecting the script. At that point, everything else is the UC.

You can see/try a working example of the above code here:

http://www.kallal.ca/WebSite11/WebForm2